# Почему такой вывод среза?

Tags: golang, slice

Я новичек в GO. И только изучаю срезы и никак не могу понять почему получается такой вывод среза a2.

CODE:

```
aSlice := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

a1 := aSlice[:5]
a2 := aSlice[6:]

n := append(a1, a2...)
fmt.Println("a1:", a1, "a2:", a2, "n:", n)
```

OUTPUT:

```
a1: [0 1 2 3 4] a2: [7 8 9 9] n: [0 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9]
```

Почему не [6, 7, 8, 9]?

Comment: Потому что все четыре среза используют один и тот же общий массив, который вы отредактировали append'ом

Comment: Спасибо, вы правы